# Connector for maven deployment?

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I have created a working maven archetype for a Vaadin/Hibernate/Spring project.  I am able to install this archetype to my local repository and use it to generate new maven projects.

Now I want to deploy the archetype to my companies internal repository, so it might be used by other developers.  However, when I run `mvn deploy` I recieve the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:
maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project 
vaadin-hibernate-archetype: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: 
No connector available to access repository maven.planet-ic.de 
(maven.planet-ic.de/planet-ic-releases) of type default using the 
available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

What is the `connector` that I am missing?

EDIT: I am not asking for someone to solve my problem, just some insight as to what the `'connector'` is.

Here is my pom.xml if it should be of interest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <groupId>de.planetic.maven.archetype.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-hibernate-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <inceptionYear>2013</inceptionYear>
    <description>
        This archetype generates a Vaadin application for use with Hibernate, and to be deployed to a Tomcat 7 server.  It may also work with other Tomcat versions and other servers.
    </description>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Maximilian Friedersdorff</name>
            <email>max.friedersdorff@planet-ic.de</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://subversion.planet-ic.de/internal/maven/archetype/pinnwand-webapp/tags/pinnwand-webapp-archetype-1.1.0</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://subversion.planet-ic.de/internal/maven/archetype/pinnwand-webapp/tags/pinnwand-webapp-archetype-1.1.0</developerConnection>
        <url>http://subversion.planet-ic.de/internal/maven/archetype/pinnwand-webapp/tags/pinnwand-webapp-archetype-1.1.0</url>
    </scm>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.planet-ic.de</id>
            <name>planet-ic-releases</name>
            <url>maven.planet-ic.de/planet-ic-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven.planet-ic.de</id>
            <name>planet-ic-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://maven.planet-ic.de/planet-ic-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>  
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: no relevant stanza from the `pom.xml` means no help

Comment: @JarrodRoberson As I said: I am not looking for help with my particular problem, but for an explanation as to what the 'connector' is.

Comment: @DB5 Wow! Nice edit. How did you do that?

Comment: @maxf130, basically just turned on syntax highlighting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on the maven repository you are trying to deploy to there are various methods available to upload your artifacts.

These methods are implemented using [Maven Wagon](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/index.html) connectors for different transport protocols (e.g. ssh,dav etc.), this is the term you are looking for.

[Apache Maven Guide to using Extensions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html) gives you an introduction on how to add connectors to your setup.

Comment: @Torten Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It just saved me!

Answer (score 3):

In the following line:

```
<url>maven.planet-ic.de/planet-ic-releases</url>
```

You need to add prefix of "file://", because you need to tell maven you are using file connector not ftp, http or something else.
And you'd better to use relative path there. For example:

```
<url>file://${project.basedir}/maven.planet-ic.de/planet-ic-releases/</url>
```

Comment: This wasn't a file repository

Comment: Still needs to be a correct url. Was a usefull remark to me

Answer (score 0):

```
 <build>
 <extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </extension>
 </extensions>
 </build>

 <distributionManagement>
 <repository>
  <id>remoteserver</id>
  <name>MyCompany Repository</name>
  <url>scp://server/path/repo</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: That is SCP, not SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others, adding the following to the pom.xml got it working for me

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue with deployment to private repo through sftp instead of scp.

Resolved it by setting the following.

**Java 11**

*pom.xml*

```xml
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>setting_id</id>
            <url>sftp://maven...../maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>setting_id_snapshot</id>
            <url>sftp://maven...../maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ...other plugins...-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

*settings.xml*

```xml
    <server>
        <id>server_id</id>
        <username>repo_user</username>
        <privateKey>/var/lib/jenk_user/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
        <directoryPermissions>744</directoryPermissions>
        <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
    </server>
```

Had tried using `<artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>` to no success.

Hope somebody finds it helpful.