# maven deploy:deploy-file fails with error Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access [url to artifactory]

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run on terminal(cmd) this command:

mvn  deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.osgi -DartifactId=org.osgi.core -Dversion=4.3.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar -DrepositoryId=[artifactory-dev-releases] -Durl=[https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] -X

to deploy given jar into our repository.

my settings.xml at ~/.m2

```
  <servers>
            <server>
                <id>artifactory-dev-releases</id>
                <username>abcdef</username>
                <password>******</password>
            </server>
            <server>
                <id>artifactory-dev-snapshots</id>
                <username>abcdef</username>
                <password>******</password>
            </server>
    </servers>
```

I am able to retrieve other jars from that artifactory with my eclipse, And this particular jar was missing so, I thought of adding it there. But it fails.

config output :

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file' with basic configurator --><BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) artifactId = org.osgi.core<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) file = /Users/amrraj/aaaa/org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) generatePom = true<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) groupId = org.osgi<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local<BR/>
      url: file:///Users/amrraj/.m2/repository/<BR/>
   layout: default<BR/>
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]<BR/>
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]<BR/>

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1 @ <BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryId = [artifactory-dev-releases]<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryLayout = default<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) uniqueVersion = true<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) url = [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/]<BR/>
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 4.3.1<BR/>
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

StackTrace:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector (DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init> (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance (BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector (DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: Cannot access [https://artifactory.corp.abc.com/artifactory/maven-aem-release-local/] using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter (DefaultTransporterProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init> (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance (BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector (DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: [https
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init> (WagonTransporter.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance (WagonTransporterFactory.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter (DefaultTransporterProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init> (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance (BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector (DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: [https
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.transport.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup (PlexusWagonProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.lookupWagon (WagonTransporter.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init> (WagonTransporter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance (WagonTransporterFactory.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter (DefaultTransporterProvider.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init> (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance (BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector (DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
```

Please note that the url is representational. The actual URL is reachable.

Am I missing something in the command I mentioned above or wagon is not proper. Please help.

Comment: I guess the URL is representational & the actual URL is reachable?

Comment: yes it is reachable. it is private and i have modified the url little bit

Comment: Have a look at these posts and see if anything helps: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/18253134/2458858

Comment: @tryingToLearn It did not help much. But i am now more confident that issue lies around wagon.